# CakePHP 2.0 app: Intermittently unable to write to Memcache cache error messages

Tags: php, cakephp, memcached, cakephp-2.0, lamp

I have a healthy, low-traffic staging server with a CakePHP app.  I am running Memcached on localhost, and all Cake caches are using Memcache as the caching engine.

For an hour or two every so often (like every 1-2 weeks), I will see errors like:

```
Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_read_users' to Memcache cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'file_map' to Memcache cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'method_cache' to Memcache cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]
```

This indicates that even core Cake caches are not able to write the the Memcache store.

I'll restart the Memcache daemon on the server, wait a few minutes, and reload the page, and still the error messages linger.

Vitals on the server look fine.

What could cause this?

Comment: Same problem here. Anybody has a solution? Happen only with Memcached...

Comment: To me this happens if I have a lot of groups defined in the Cache engine.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that CakeShell was accessed from a user (i.e. root) with permissions higher than those of normal php execution (www-data) so those cache files can not be accessed or changed later from the normal process?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Memcached` configurations. Maybe the max ItemSize has been reached.
You can start Memcached in interactive mode:

```
memcached -u root --v
```

and see if some SERVER ERROR log appears.

You can try increasing the item size:

```
memcached -u root --vv -I 5m
```